# Merge a list of list into one list python

Tags: python, list, indexing, sorting

I was asked to merge a list of sorted lists into one sorted list, using a list that holds all candidates to be moved next to the final output list. I wrote this code and I get index error. Can anyone help please!

```
    import copy
    def getNext(lst, index):
        if len(lst)< index+1:
            return None
        else:
            return lst[index]
    def multi_merge_v2(lst_of_lsts):
        myLst= copy.copy(lst_of_lsts)
        candidates=[]
        for lst in myLst:
            if lst!=[]:
                candidates.append(lst[0])
        indexes= [0]*len(candidates)
        merged=[]
        while candidates !=[]:
            Min = min(candidates)
            merged += [Min]
            index = indexes[candidates.index(Min)]
            indexes[index]+=1
            nextCan = getNext(myLst[index], indexes[index])
            if nextCan == None:
                myLst.remove(myLst[index])
                candidates.remove(Min)
                indexes.remove(indexes[index])
            else:
                candidates[index]=nextCan
        return merged
```

Comment: Do you have to use this algorithm?

Comment: If you really want to reinvent the wheel (exercise or whatever), I'd generally suggest splitting your algorithm into more managable components and testing them individually. Otherwise, go with @msvalkon's suggestion.

Comment: No, but I have to save all "candidates" in a list and use them to get next element in my new merged list. That's why using 'sorted' is not very useful.

Comment: I have read your code a couple of times and i am sorry but i got lost. Could i ask you to comment the code to explain what you are trying to de in each step. Also, when using double list. try using copy.deepcopy. as copy.copy makes a new list of references to the old inner lists. May that might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
merged = lst_of_lsts[-1]
for lst in lst_of_lsts[0:-1]:
    merged += lst
merged.sort()
```